# Getting co.myFunction is not a function error

Tags: angular

I am getting below error while executing the angularjs code 
HTML code:

```
<tbody>
              <tr>
              <td class=" ">1<sup>st</sup>
                <div class="box draggable" 
                      appDraggable
                      (draggStart)="ondraggStart()">Delete1</div></td>
                <td class=""><button class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditClass">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn  ">Delete</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td class=" ">2<sup>nd</sup></td>
                <td class=""><button class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditClass">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn  ">Delete</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td class=" ">3<sup>rd</sup></td>
                <td class=""><button class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditClass">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn  ">Delete</button></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
```

app.component.ts file code:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
ondraggStart = function(){
console.log("got drag start");
}
}
```

Below is my 
draggble.directive.ts code:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from 
'@angular/core';
@Directive({
selector: '[appDraggable]'})
export class DraggableDirective {
@HostBinding('class.draggable') draggable=true;
@Output() draggStart =new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
private dragging =false;
@HostListener('pointerdown',['$event']) onpointerdown(event:PointerEvent): 
void{
  this.dragging=true;
  this.draggStart.emit(event);
}
}
```

After executing i am getting below error:

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: _co.ondraggStart is not a function
> at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AddClassComponent.html:24)
> at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
> ```

Please let me know if someone faced this error in angular project

Comment: Might be a typo in `co.ondragStart`. To help you further we need to see the actual html and ts for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not much info to go on here.  But if "ondragStart" is supposed to be a built-in UI event, then perhaps capitalize the "d" and see if that resolves things.

Answer (score 0):

By loading bootstrap library my issue is resolved.